# cisco: configure (login|exec|motd) banner via copy

Tags: cisco

if I copy a config from a tftp server to running config of an IOS (various => v12 device which currently has nothing in nvram, the banner part of the config is not included in the new running config.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

banner config example (tried both):

```
banner exec ^C
text
^c
```

or (where "-" = deliminator)

```
banner exec -
text
-
```

Comment: what IOS device and what IOS version?

Comment: Can you also post the config you are trying to copy?

Comment: using >12.1. Issue with all releases.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and mention at least one full device type and version (full version like 12.1(11)EA1). Also, the examples you give, did you try them literally, i.e. with the banner being just the word "text" ? Or did you actually test with another banner text which you then replaced with the word "text" in your post? I don't want to sound pedantic about this but it is important to know - e.g. bug CSCsu57889 causes banner lines starting with ! ; or # to be ignored.

Comment: Also, after doing the copy, do you see the "banner" command in your running config, but the text is missing? Or is the banner command missing entirely? And when you execute the copy tftp command, is there any error?

Comment: After testing with the actual "banner motd - text - , it copies it into it's running config. Before it did not appear visible in the running config at all. I was working with 3560g series Switches running varios IOS version. During the initial banner I had  used characters such as "_|", perhaps that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The banner copied successfully when posted at the end of the config to be copied. 
I used a standard ascii deliminator (not as seen in the actual running-config "^C") and added "end" right after the ending deliminator. This worked.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Can you please mark it as "accepted" (click the grey checkmark) so the question doesn't keep popping up as unanswered? Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

try specifying the boot image boot, e.g. `system bootflash:n5000.bin`

```
config t
banner exec #
********
* test *
********
#
```

[Configuring Terminal Banners](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/configuration/guide/ffun_c/fcf004.html#wp1001226)

Banners can be customized with the use of banner tokens. Tokens are keywords in the form $(token) that, when used in a banner message, display the currently configured value of the token argument (for example, the router host name, domain name, or IP address).

[image]

Comment: So how does this make the copy from tftp work?

Comment: what does the boot image have to do with it, and mwhy should tokens help?